# Firebase Callback Interface needs to be declared final?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, final, anonymous-class

Following is the code and on one of the line, android studio is asking me to declare as final

```java
      public void getFullName(GetFullNameCallback getFullNameCallback) { usersRef.child(mAuth.getUid()).child("fN").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            getFullNameCallback.onCallback(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
      }


      private interface GetFullNameCallback {
        void onCallback(String fullName);
      }
```

At the `getFullNameCallback.onCallback()` in `onDataChange`, it is underlined red as it says `getFullNameCallback` should be declared final but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774), it is just fine??

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class ?

Comment: Sorry for being a noob cuz I don't see how this could help me... Please elaborate for a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/5640649), *only final variables are accessible inside an anonymous class*.

In your code you receive `getFullNameCallback` as parameter in `getFullName` method (it is not a local variable inside the code which creates a new instance of an `ValueEventListener`).

Moreover you use it (`getFullNameCallback`) *inside* the anonymous class `ValueEventListener`, so, `getFullNameCallback` must be `final` in order to be used (again, it is explained why in the linked post).

Comment: Okay... but Is this new? because from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774  they don't declare it as final

Comment: @wolfrevokcats specifically related to android I can't tell, sorry. But in Java in general, as far as I know this works this way